# Debug assembly with python.net script

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, pycharm, python.net

I would like to know if it is poasible to debug a .NET assembly called from ampython.net script ? I tried to attach (debug) the solution to PyCharm (the python IDE I use) but without success.

Usong IronPython is not a solution as I need scientific libraries such as numpy and Co.

thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Various-debugging-scenarios-of-embedded-CPython